# why does a device node need to be made in udev when you plug in a device into your computer?

Tags: udev, devices

Why does a device node need to be made in udev when you plug in a device into your computer?

Why does a device node need to exist?

Comment: Well… the question is pertinent. Yes indeed… you could easily achieve the same result… manually… right from the command line. Of course, that'd need some knowledge and there would certainly be a vast amount of so-called quiche-eaters wanting this task to be… automated… ;-)

Comment: To a first approximation, everything in Linux is a file. (a) We have this fine tree structure which gives us a hierarchic map of all the file resources on the system. (b) Let's overload it with fake entries like /proc, /run, /sys which allow us to interact with the Kernel. (c) If we can plug and unplug devices, let's dynamically create and destroy appropriate entries for them in /dev. As it happens, the boot process includes exploring *all* the hardware and building /dev from scratch anyway.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does a device node need to be made in udev

You got that backwards: it's udev that creates that device node.

And whether and which kind of device nodes are created depends on the kind of hardware you plug in: It makes a difference whether you plug in a storage block device, a GPU or a network card.

> Why does a device node need to exist?

Because operations on device nodes are the way that software interacts with hardware. Your question is identical to the question of

> how does a program on Linux interact with hardware?

and the answer is:

It depends, but it usually opens the device node and performs `read`, `write` or `ioctl` on it, or it uses the node's properties to initiate other kernel operations (like `mount` does with `fsopen`).